# Android app crashing when deep link added something wrong in the main activity.java

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am developing an app on unity. I was planing to establish the deep linking process separately on android and ios. I established the deep linking process on android as follows.
 my androidmanifest is this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.liveroom.liveroom" >
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GalleryUpdater"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

and my main activity which is GallaryUpdater.java is as follows (only the oncreate and the returning data methods)

```
//deeplink intent catcher

    public static String id;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Uri data = intent.getData();
        id=data.getLastPathSegment();
    }

       //return id vale
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
```

when I build this on unity on an android device, the app crashes when opening from the menu of the device. but app works perfectly well when open through a deep link. If anyone could show me what causes the problem here. Thank you

Comment: post the stack trace.

Comment: Any chance that `data` is null when you launch via the app launcher?

Comment: Im not sure how to get the stack trace Im new to this environment @JoxTraex

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html

Comment: You told your app crashed then what message was shown due to the crash in Log is stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you for the support everyone. The problem was with the data being null when open from the launcher as @mkasberg said. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a null check and try

```
if(intent != null && intent.getData() != null)
{
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    id=data.getLastPathSegment();
}
```